# Helper class in classes implements protocol

Tags: swift

I have protocol ChartData

```
protocol ChartData {
    var dataHelper: DataHelper { get set }
    var chartValues: [ChartValues] { get set }
}
```

And class implement this protocol

```
class SalesChartData: ChartData {
     var dataHelper: DataHelper
     var chartValues: [ChartValues] = []

     init() {
         dataHelper = DataHelper(data: ??? how to pass SalesChartData here ???)
     }
}
```

And helper class:

```
class DataHelper {

    var data: ChartData

    init(data: ChartData) {
        self.data = data
    }

    // use ChartData data.chartValues for example...
}
```

Question is how to pass `SalesChartData` to `DataHelper` (pass 'self' doesn't work)? I need access to `DataHelper` in every class that implements `ChartData` protocol. Am I doing it wrong? How it should be constructed? I want to filter, etc. passed data `chartValues` in `DataHelper`. Appreciate any ideas

// Edit:

I did something like this, but this construction is rly not elegant. How to improve it?

```
init() {
    dataHelper = DataHelper()
    dataHelper.setData(data: self)
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems flawed. You have a protocol which has a variable which again which is of a type which again has a variable of the same protocol. This looks similar to the problem you face when setting the value of a variable inside it's setter. _infinite loop_

Comment: You can't do what you want because in first phase initialization swift object you can't touch `self`, but if you make `dataHelper` as optional in protocol, you will be able to `dataHelper = DataHelper(self)`. Also I see that you will have retain cycle here, to avoid it, you need to do weak reference for `data` in `DataHelper `. But to make `data` as `weak` in `DataHelper`, your protocol should be inherited from `class` : `protocol ChartData: class`

Answer (score 0):

Try with **lazy**:

```
class SalesChartData: ChartData {
     lazy var dataHelper: DataHelper = DataHelper(data: self)
     var chartValues: [ChartValues] = []
}
```